# When inflate layout, once view disappear

Tags: android, layout-inflater

First, sorry by my English.

I have a listview and when inflate this ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:foreground="@drawable/foreground"
android:background="@color/white_background" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >     

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/v_vertical_line"
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/blue_main" />
```

WORKS!!

But i need a minHeight because its possible than a textview have a large string

so if i modify this xml to..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="80dp"
android:foreground="@drawable/foreground"
android:background="@color/white_background" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >     

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/v_vertical_line"
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/blue_main" />
```

The last view (v_vertical_line) disappear.

I want a row than have a minimun height (80dp) and the view (v_vertical_line) go to the top to bottom.

ALL LAYOUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:foreground="@drawable/foreground"
android:background="@color/white_background" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >     

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/v_vertical_line"
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/blue_main" />


        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:border_color="#FF000000"
            app:border_width="2dp" /> 

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout2" 
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

textView3 can have a large string

Comment: have you tried tried fragment layout instead. nested relative layouts is not a good thing to do.

Comment: Could you post all layout? Where is the TextView?